# EF with non-POCO class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a custom `Date` class that wraps a `DateTime` object to expose only the Date portion.

I'm trying to include it in a entity, but getting an exception:

```
error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 6:No
mapping specified for properties Goal.Date in Set Goal.\r\nAn Entity with Key
(PK) will not round-trip when:\r\n  Entity is type [EFCodeFirstSandbox.Goal]
```

What gives? How do I get my custom class to play nice in the EF world?

Here's a dumbed-down version of the custom `Date` class:

```
public class Date
{
    private DateTime value;
    public Date(DateTime date)
    {
        this.value = date.Date;
    }
    public static implicit operator Date(DateTime date)
    {
        return new Date(date);
    }
    public static implicit operator DateTime(Date date)
    {
        return date.value;
    }
}
```

Entity class using `Date`:

```
public class Goal
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Date Date { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: This `Date` class is just used for illustrative purposes. I'm interested in knowing how to map custom, non-POCO classes, not how to represent a date in SQL. :)

Answer (score 1):

In fact EF says: "I don't know what to with a `Date` class". As the `Date` property is a reference to another class, EF wants the mapping of this class *and* the association between `Goal` and `Date` to be defined. Neither of them are.

I would map a full `DateTime` property to the database column and create a computed property that returns the date part of this `DateTime` property.

For instance (as @Excommunicated pointed out):

```
partial class Goal
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]
    public DateTime DateTrunc
    { 
        get { return this.Date.Date; }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Can you point me to anything that will tell me more about creating computed property?

Comment: create another property on your Goal class the returns your Date type and simply calculates it from the DateTime property. Mark the Date property with the [NotMapped] attribute, or mark it not mapped wherever you declare your mappings, keys and relationships etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do what you are after. You need to use types Entity framework knows how to map. What you need to do is use DateTime and use a readonly or unmapped property to expose your custom type.

```
public class Goal
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    // Read only field not mapped
    public Date CustomDate { get { return this.Date; }}

    // OR... specificallly ignored property that enables date setting

    [NotMapped] // In System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema namespace
    public Date CustomDate { 
                                get { 
                                     return this.Date; 
                                }
                                set {
                                    this.Date = value;
                                }
                           }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @GertArnold said, keep the column type as `DateTime`. Add a partial class definition to expose any additional properties that you require.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get means that the EF try to resolvve the `Date` type to a table (like any other class you make) and there is no primary key for type `Date`.
You should use `DateTime` and decorate the property with `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`.